# How to call function in directive file from html in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and am trying to get a function to fire on the onblur of an input.

I am trying to call either the function called ball2 or ball from the onblur of the directive.
The javascript of the directive is as follows (which contains ball2 and ball):

```
'use strict';

(function() {
  angular.module('theapp').directive('number', number);

  number.$inject = ['$filter', 'Global', 'Product'];

  function number($filter, Global, Product) {
    return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      scope: {
        vm: '=numberScope',
        product: '=numberProduct',
        column: '=numberColumn',
        errorcheck: '=numberErrorcheck',
        onblurfunc: '=numberFunc'
      },
      templateUrl: 'app/directives/number.tpl.html',
      replace: true,
      link: link,
      ball2: ball2
    };

    function ball2() {
      alert('ball2');
    }

    function link(scope, element, attributes, ngModelController) {
      var isTotal = angular.isDefined(attributes.numberIsTotal);
      var productSet = scope.product.set;

      scope.css = {
        modelChanged: modelChanged,
        textBold: textBold,
        textMuted: textMuted,
        errorClass: errorClass,
        ball: ball
      };

      if (ngModelController) {
        validateInput();
        validateDisplay();
        trackChange();
      }

      function ball() {
        alert('ball');
      }

      function format(value) {
        var options = isTotal ? '{"showZero": "true"}' : undefined;
        return $filter('translateNumber')(value, options);
      }

      function modelChanged() {
        var columnTracked = scope.vm.data.columns.tracked(productSet.productNo, scope.column);
        return productSet.tracked && columnTracked;
      }

      function textBold() {
        return isTotal && productSet.totalMake;
      }

      function textMuted() {
        return isTotal && !productSet.totalMake;
      }

      function errorClass() {
        return scope.errorcheck;
      }
      function trackChange() {
        ngModelController.$parsers.push(track);

        function track(value) {
          productSet.tracked = Product.changes.track(context());
          return value;

          function context() {
            return {
              changes: scope.vm.data.changes || [],
              column: scope.column,
              modelValue: ngModelController.$modelValue || 0,
              product: productSet,
              productNo: productSet.productNo,
              urlKey: scope.vm.data.urlKey,
              errorcheck: scope.errorcheck,
              onblurfunc: scope.onblurfunc,
              value: value
            };
          }
        }
      }

      function validateDisplay() {
        ngModelController.$formatters.push(format);
      }

      function validateInput() {
        ngModelController.$parsers.push(positiveNumber);

        function positiveNumber(value) {
          var posNum = $filter('toPositiveNumber')(value);
          if (!posNum) {
            ngModelController.$viewValue = format(posNum);
            ngModelController.$render();            
          }
          return posNum;
        }
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

The html of the directive is (I changed input to inp so it appears in the question):
-->

The directive is being used in several pages.
Please help me to call one of the "ball" functions (or explain to me what I need to change in the functions to enable one of them to be called in onblur).
Thanks

Comment: The 'app/directives/number.tpl.html' is just an input. Whenever I try to show this html it keeps getting hidden. In that input I would like to set the onblur in the input to a function contained in the javascript above (either the function ball() or ball2()).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where you bound your element to a blur event. Try putting an

```
element.bind('blur', function() {
    //Call functions here
```

});

in the directive.